# How to write the following equation in dimensionless form?

Tags: nonlinear-system

We have the following equation $$mg\sin(\theta)=kx\left(1-\frac{L}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\right)$$ and we are asked to put it in the following dimensionless form: $$1-\frac{h}{u}=\frac{R}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}.$$ According to me $u=x/a$ and $R=L/a$ then we have $$\frac{R}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}=1-\frac{mg\sin(\theta)}{kx}$$ which would imply that $$\frac{h}{u}=\frac{mg\sin(\theta)}{kx}$$ which is weird since $u=x/a.$ Where am I going wrong?

**Edit:** Here I am adding the units of each term in the equation given above:

$m:\text{mass},$ $g:\text{acceleration due to gravity so }ms^{-2}$,$k:\text{ spring constant so }Nm^{-1},\{x,L,a\}:\text{length}.$

Here is the original question **Part(b**) in case I made any typos:

[image]

Comment: The $h$ in the first equation is not the same as the $h$ in the second equation, or is it?

Comment: Oh I am sorry the h should be an a in the first equation.

Comment: @citronrose Please see the edit...

Comment: It would also help to have a description of what the variables stand for and what their units are.

Comment: Will do that in a second...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us rewrite the equilibrium position of the bead as 
\begin{align*}
\frac{mg\sin\theta}{kx} & = 1 - \frac{L_0}{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}} \\
1 - \frac{mg\sin\theta}{kx} & = \frac{L_0}{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}} \\
1 - \frac{mg\sin\theta}{kx} & = \frac{L_0}{a\sqrt{(x/a)^2 + 1}}
\end{align*}
Define the dimensionless variable $u = x/a$. Then
\begin{align*}
1 - \frac{mg\sin\theta}{kau} & = \frac{L_0}{a\sqrt{u^2 + 1}}.
\end{align*}
The corresponding $R$ and $h$ are 
$$ R = \frac{L_0}{a} \ \ \textrm{ and } \ \ h = \frac{mg\sin\theta}{ka}. $$
Let us check that $R$ and $h$ are indeed dimensionless. It is clear that $R$ is dimensionless since $L_0$ and $a$ are lengths. The dimension of $mg$ is 
$$ [mg] = \frac{\textrm{mass}\times\textrm{length}}{\textrm{time}^2} $$
and the dimension of $k$ is 
$$ [k] = \frac{[mg]}{[x]} = \frac{\textrm{mass}}{\textrm{time}^2}. $$
Consequently, $h$ is also dimensionless. Here, the square bracket denotes the dimension of the quantity of interest.

Comment: Do you know this problem?

Comment: @SuperMario No.